# UI mask and elements not visible after Async scene change

Tags: unity, async

i have an async loading scene system that redirects to a loading scene and then to the target scene. The function works properly although i found out that some UI elements dont work directly on scene load. For instance i have a ui bar that acts as a fill bar for objectives, (as you collect points it increments) which when i run the scene directly works fine but as soon as i load that scene async i need to manually enable the object or have it get enabled with a button press to work.

i call the loading through this function

```
Utilities.LoadSceneLoading(Utilities.Scene.GameScene, Utilities.Scene.LoadingSceneGame);
```

The actual function is this

```
  private class LoadingMono : MonoBehaviour { }

  private static Action onLoaderCallback;
  private static AsyncOperation asyncOperation;

    public static void LoaderCallback()
    {
        if (onLoaderCallback != null)
        {
            onLoaderCallback();
            onLoaderCallback = null;
        }
    }

    public static void LoadSceneLoading(Scene scene, Scene _loadingScene)
    {
        onLoaderCallback = () =>
        {
            GameObject loadingObject = new GameObject("Loading GO");
            loadingObject.AddComponent<LoadingMono>().StartCoroutine(LoadSceneAsync(scene));

        };
        SceneManager.LoadScene(_loadingScene.ToString());
    }

    private static IEnumerator LoadSceneAsync(Scene scene)
    {
        yield return null;
        asyncOperation = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(scene.ToString());

        while (!asyncOperation.isDone)
        {
            yield return null;
        }

    }
```

And in the loading scene i have this script that get enabled after an animation event

```
public class LoaderCallback : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool isFirstUpdate = true;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (isFirstUpdate)
        {
            
            Utilities.LoaderCallback();
            isFirstUpdate = false;
        }
    }
}
```

and the object that enables it is this

```
  private void Update()
    {
        ShowScene();
    }

 void ShowScene()
    {
        if (canMove)
        {
            time -= Time.deltaTime;
            if (time <= 0)
            {
                loaderCallback.enabled = true;
            }
        }

    }

    public void EnableCallBack()
    {
        canMove = true;
    }
```

The whole process works fine as i need it to but i have those issues with the UI which for now , for the count bar , i have kind of fixed by having it inactive on start and enable it on the play button press but since i do have more elements and i dont want to have to try it out everytime i add something i would like some help in understanding why it doesnt allow the UI elements to appear! Thank you!

Edit:

basically what it doesnt show is an inverted UI mask that i have.

```
public class CutoutMaskUI : Image
{
    public override Material materialForRendering {
        get
        {
            Material material = new Material(base.materialForRendering);
            material.SetInt("_StencilComp", (int)CompareFunction.NotEqual);
            return material;
        }
    }
}
```

i have a UI element acting as a border around an image set to fill in two separate objects, the count bar and a selection bar acting like a clock going around in a circle , these two items do not render on start and if i disable them / enable them in runtime they suddenly appear.

Basicaly the red fill image doesnt get rendered in the circle and the black outline in the count bar

[image: The two objects with the cutout mask script]

Comment: I think we need more information in order to help. Your scene loading code seems fine. The problem is probably somewhere else, possibly in the code that drives your UI, but that is merely a guess. Can you put together a minimum verifiable example and share scene setup(s) and other code that may be involved?

Comment: Thank you i edited my question!

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem with the inverted mask, and found [this thread in Unity Forums](https://forum.unity.com/threads/ui-inverse-mask.342324/), so I tried what styrbo suggested. But didn't work initially, then I tried changing maskable to false and back to true in the Fix Coroutine, and it worked!
So, this is what I added to the CutoutMaskUI class:

```
protected override void Start()
{
    base.Start();
    StartCoroutine(Fix());
}

/// Fix for async loading scenes
private IEnumerator Fix()
{
    yield return null;
    maskable = false;
    maskable = true;
}
```